# Auto-Generated Interface Implementation

Tags: vb.net, oop, interface

When implementing the IDisposable interface, the Must-Override method: Dispose; is auto-generated.  That auto-generated method has a very small amount of code and comments.  I'd like to do the same thing with one of my own Must-Override methods.  The only example I can come up with is in an Inheriting a Base Class, since as far as I know, you can't put implementation details in an Interface.

So, starting with this:

```
Public Class MyBase
    Public MustOverride Sub OverrideMe()
        Me.DidOverride = True
        //'Use this method to do things
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyClass

End Class
```

When I type "Inherits MyBase", I'd like to see:

```
Public Class MyBase
    Public MustOverride Sub OverrideMe()
        Me.DidOverride = True
        //'Use this method to do things
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyClass
    Inherits MyBase

    Protected Overrides Sub OverrideMe()
        Me.DidOverride = True
        //'Use this method to do things
    End Sub
End Class
```

Or something to that effect.  I could also do this in an interface if told how.

Comment: It's specific behaviour built into Visual Studio. You *may* be able to build an add-in (plug-in, package, whatever) but that would have to be installed in VS to have it work - and if you want help with that, we'd need to know what version of VS you're working on.

Comment: That's actually a great idea. The real goal is to put my DLL free for download on my website, to let other devs create their own GUI's that use my code as the processing power. Part of that is: I give them the power to make their own class(es) that implement one of many base classes, and I would like the implementation examples or comments to pop up when they do so.  The alternative is just some lengthy documentation, which very well may be the answer.  This wouldn't be a problem if it were within my organization.  The add-on idea would be perfect in that case.